# Two Consecutive Sorting with Different Criterion

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to make a sorter that sort the number of int list.

When the list given, first it changes that into binary and check how many 1's in there, and sort them in ascending order first.

Then, they re-order among the numbers that has same number of 1's in their binary, if one is bigger than the other, re-sort in ascending order.

For example for given `[1,2,3,4]`

it returns `[1,2,4,3]`

```
def Sort(nums):
    #to deprecated the duplicated nums
    nums = list(set(nums))
    #input nums are list 

    search_list = [] #it contains (dec, bin, card)

    for i in range(len(nums)):

        binary = bin(nums[i])[2:] #it returns str of binary of given input
        count = 0

        for j in range(0, len(binary)):
            if binary[j] == str(1):
                count += 1
            else:
                pass 

        dec_bin_card = (nums[i], binary, count)

        search_list.append(dec_bin_card)

    sorted_draft = sorted(search_list, key = lambda x: x[2]) #sort by cardinality 

    for i in range(len(sorted_draft)-1):
        if sorted_draft[i][2] == sorted_draft[i+1][2]: #if has same count 
            if sorted_draft[i][0] > sorted_draft[i+1][0]:
                sorted_draft[i], sorted_draft[i+1] = sorted_draft[i+1], sorted_draft[i]
            else:
                pass

    sorted_final = [sorted_draft[i][0] for i in range(len(sorted_draft))]

    return sorted_final
```

Comment: Your result seems to be fine. 1, 2, 4 each have one bit, 3 has two bits.

Comment: Unless you're presenting just the desired output and failing to present the actual

Comment: @I thought too.. but this is my homework and there's a test case to check wehther this algorithm fine or not. but keep failing and successing only for the combination of numbers 1 to 31... how can I check the error in this case?

Comment: Try to sort the numbers 32-64. It's a small enough range that you can  check by hand.

Comment: I think your problem is `nums = list(set(nums))`. You could be deleting elements that way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one line solution:

```
sorted_nums = sorted(nums, key=lambda x: (bin(x).count('1'), x))
```

Your implementation seems fine, even though it is very inefficient. The problem is most likely in the line

```
nums = list(set(nums))
```

This deletes any duplicate elements in the list, which seems counter to the spirit of the problem.

Comment: sorted_nums = sorted(nums, key=lambda x: (bin(x).count(1), x))
 this returns error like TypeError: must be str, not int

Comment: @delinco 1 just needs to be replaced by '1' and it works.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon. Thanks for the catch. Time to get some sleep :)